# Inno Setup / ISTool: Detect local computer's IP address(es)

Tags: c++, inno-setup, pascalscript, istool

In the [code] section of my [ISS](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) script I want to detect the local machine's IP addresses. What is the most elegant way to accomplish this? Is there a Win32 DLL I can import via ["external"](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptdll.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any prepackaged DLLs that you could call but writing one should be too difficult.  I found this post on the InnoSetup newsgroup: http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup.code/msg09240.html
that might give you a start.